# Unexpected result of summation

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, debugging

I wrote a small module that gives me an incorrect output-set. It should be a single number!

I don't understand what went wrong.

This is the form of summation used:
$$\frac{1}{2} (b-a) \sum_{i=1}^n w_i\,f\left(\frac{b-a}{2}x_i+\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$$ where ${x,w}$ are generated by `GaussianQuadratureWeights` command:

```
  Needs["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]
    GaussLegendreQuadrature[a_, b_, n_] := Module[{weights, i},
       (* GaussianQuadratureWeights[n, a, b] gives a list of the
          n pairs {Subscript[x, i], Subscript[w, i]} of the elementary
          n-point Gaussian formula for quadrature on the interval a to b,
          where Subscript[w, i] is the weight of the abscissa
          Subscript[x, i].*)

       weights = GaussianQuadratureWeights[n, -1, 1];
       Return[(b - a)/2 \!\(
    \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\(
    \*SubscriptBox[\(weights\), \(i, 2\)]\ f[
    \*FractionBox[\(a + b\), \(2\)] + 
    \*FractionBox[\(b - a\), \(2\)] 
    \*SubscriptBox[\(weights\), \(i, 1\)]]\)\)]];

    f[x_] := Sin[x];
    GaussLegendre[0, 1, 8]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see two problems : you need to include the function as an argument to `GaussLegendreQuadrature` and you need to call it with the correct name.

```
GaussLegendreQuadrature[a_, b_, n_, f_] := Module[{weights, i},
  weights = GaussianQuadratureWeights[n, -1, 1];
  (b-a)/2 * Sum[weights[[i, 2]] f[(a + b)/2 + (b - a)/2 weights[[i, 1]]], {i, 1,n}]]    

GaussLegendreQuadrature[0, 1, 8, Sin]

(* 0.459698 *)
```

Comment: Compare the result of your routine with `N[Integrate[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}], 20]`.

Comment: @J.M. Just trying to make the code work; didn't mean to check whether it does the right thing. And I missed the factor `(b-a)/2`.

Comment: for one thing, b.gatessucks missed the `(b - a)/2*`. Still, it is a good result

Comment: @user465292 Yes, sorry about that, fixed now.

Comment: There's no strict need to pass the function as argument. Failing to do so makes a very bad interface, but nevertheless works. Mathematica will just use the global version it finds at evaluation time, which is the one defined directly before the call, i.e. the one @user465292 intended to be called. And as far as I can see he *did* use the correct name (see at the end of the line containing the first `\*SubScriptBox`. And yes, I looked in the edit history, and that part doesn't seem to have been changed).

Answer (score 25):

There's absolutely no need to load a package if all you want to do is simple Gauss-Legendre quadrature:

```
GaussLegendreQuadrature[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, n_Integer: 10, prec_: MachinePrecision] :=
  Module[{nodes, weights},
         {nodes, weights} = Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[n, prec]];
         (b - a) weights.Map[Function[x, f], Rescale[nodes, {0, 1}, {a, b}]]]

GaussLegendreQuadrature[Sin[x], {x, -1, 3}, 10, 20]
1.530294802468585173

N[Integrate[Sin[x], {x, -1, 3}], 20]
1.5302948024685851747
```

---

OP does not consider the code to be sufficiently self-evident, so here's a few notes on the implementation:

- `` Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[n, prec]] `` is intended to give the Gauss-Legendre weights for the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$; this is equivalent to `GaussianQuadratureWeights[n, 0, 1, prec]`.
- `Rescale[x, {0, 1}, {a, b}] == a + (b - a) x`; figuring what this substitution has to do with the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is left as an exercise.
- Dot products are an excellent way to do sums of the form $\sum_i w_i f_i$.

---

Since OP has already accepted the other answer, for the purposes of making this post more useful and convenient than it already is, I will just include **advanced** methods for generating the Gauss-Legendre nodes and weights had `` NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[] `` or `GaussianQuadratureWeights[]` not been available. I'll be linking to the papers explaining these methods, so I won't say more about them.

Here's the [Golub-Welsch algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-69-99647-1):

```
{nodes, weights} = MapAt[Map[First, #]^2 &, Eigensystem[N[
                SparseArray[{{k_, k_} -> 1, {j_, k_} /; Abs[j - k] == 1 :> 
                            With[{i = Min[j, k]}, i/Sqrt[4 i^2 - 1]]}, {n, n}]/2,
                    prec]], 2]
```

Here's [Laurie's algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8685-7_9):

```
{nodes, weights} = {Diagonal[#2]^2/2, First[#1]^2} & @@ 
     Take[SingularValueDecomposition[
       N[SparseArray[{{k_, k_} :> k/Sqrt[k (2 k - 1)],
                      {j_, k_} /; j == k + 1 :> k/Sqrt[k (2 k + 1)]}, {n, n}],
         prec], Tolerance -> 0], 2]
```

The two methods are intimately related, in the sense that the eigenvalues of a symmetric positive definite matrix are related to the singular values of that matrix's Cholesky triangle. Here, the underlying symmetric positive definite matrix (the *Jacobi matrix*) is constructed such that its characteristic polynomial is a suitably normalized Legendre polynomial, whose roots are needed for Gaussian quadrature. Again, see the linked papers for more details.

Comment: I have too admit, it look very cool, and probably works way better than my version, but way out of my league. Though, I will browse through docs to find out out what code does. Thanks !

Comment: I'll write a few explanatory notes, then.