# Computing the coefficients for Gaussian integral

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I wrote a small script to find the Gaussian integral points and weights:

```
FindInstance[{Table[x[i]^j, {j, 0, 2 # + 1}, {i, 0, #}].Table[
       w[i], {i, 0, #}] == 
     Table[Integrate[x^i, {x, -1, 1}], {i, 0, 2 # + 1}], 
    Less @@ Table[x[i], {i, 0, #}]} , 
   Flatten[{Table[x[i], {i, 0, #}], Table[w[i], {i, 0, #}]}]] &[n]
```

For $n$ is small the script is working:

```
n=1
{{x[0] -> -(1/Sqrt[3]), x[1] -> 1/Sqrt[3], w[0] -> 1, w[1] -> 1}}

n=2
{{x[0] -> -Sqrt[(3/5)], x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> Sqrt[3/5], w[0] -> 5/9, 
  w[1] -> 8/9, w[2] -> 5/9}}
```

but for $n\ge5$, the script is extremely slow.

Is it possible to speed up the script? If not, is it possible if I only want numerical results?

Comment: Is it a programming practice or you just need the Gaussian integral weights? If the latter, search `GaussianQuadratureWeights` in the document.

Comment: @xzczd just for fun.

Comment: You are aware that `LegendreP[]` is built-in?

Comment: Apropos: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6966) is an answer that uses some heavy machinery to generate Gauss-Legendre quadrature rules.

Comment: FWIW: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34047) is an even more elaborate procedure.

Comment: @J. M. It is cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to many quadrature points (say, less than 1000), then the easiest way to get them is simply by finding the eigenvalues of the tridiagonal Jacobi matrix, the [Golub Welsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#The_Golub-Welsch_algorithm).

Here's [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/12209/210969) describing the rules for the matrix elements.

```
pointsAndWeightsGaussLegendre[n_] := Module[{jacobi},
  jacobi = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
  Do[jacobi[[i, i + 1]] = 
    jacobi[[i + 1, i]] = i/Sqrt[4.0 i^2 - 1], {i, n - 1}];
  jacobi = Eigensystem@jacobi;
  jacobi[[2]] = (2 #[[1]]^2 &) /@ jacobi[[2]];
  Chop@Transpose@Sort@Transpose@jacobi]
```

This gives the same results as the OP's code, but much faster.  Even 1000 points can be calculated in a fraction of a second.

[image]

I know there are plenty of codes out there to give the quadrature points and weights, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/34047/210969) and [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/math_src/arbitrary_weight_rule/arbitrary_weight_rule.html), I just find this one to be intuitive and easy to implement.  I've used Gauss-Hermite quadrature quite often, and so I had this function already laying around:

```
pointsAndWeightsGaussHermite[n_] := Module[{jacobi},
  jacobi = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
  Do[jacobi[[i, i + 1]] = jacobi[[i + 1, i]] = Sqrt[i/2.0], {i, 
    n - 1}];
  jacobi = Eigensystem@jacobi;
  jacobi[[2]] = (Sqrt[\[Pi]] #[[1]]^2 &) /@ jacobi[[2]];
  Chop@Transpose@Sort@Transpose@jacobi]
```