# Stop iteration during solving of an Integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I am trying to solve the following integral equation numerically in mathematica:

$f(x) = 1 + \int_0^1 dy \left(1-3xy\right)f(y)$. The exact solution is $f(x)=\frac{8}{3}-2x$. I can get the desired result for fix number of iteration as follows:

```
dim = 11;
<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;
dat = GaussianQuadratureWeights[dim, 0, 1];
dat2 = Table[dat[[i, 2]], {i, 1, dim}];
approxsoln = Table[1, {i, 1, dim}];
f = Table[1, {i, 1, dim}];
Kn = Table[(1 - 3 dat[[i, 1]] dat[[j, 1]]), {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, 
dim}];
exactsoln = Table[(8/3 - 2 dat[[i, 1]]), {i, 1, dim}];

Do[values = f + Total[Kn approxsoln dat2, 1];
 Print[iter, ",  " , approxsoln[[1]] , ",  ", exactsoln[[1]]];
 approxsoln = values, {iter, 1, 20}]
```

Note that I am using Gaussian Quadrature for the numerical integration for the faster evaluation of the actual problem.  Now, instead of fix number iteration, I am trying to set a fix accuracy to stop the iteration ($\chi^2$ test ) as follows:

```
chsq=0.;
acc=0.001;
Do[values = f + Total[Kn approxsoln dat2, 1];
chsq = Max[Abs[1 - values/approxsoln], chsq]; 
If[chsq < acc, Break[]]; approxsoln = values; 
Print[iter, ",  " , approxsoln[[1]] , ",  ", exactsoln[[1]]], {iter, 
1, 20}]
```

But unable to stop the iteration. Does anybody have any idea what am I doing wrong or how to do this? Thanks in advance for the help and for your time.

Comment: If all you want is to use the Gauss-Legendre abscissas and weights, there's no need to load that package. See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6962), for instance.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know I can define it locally instead of loading the package. As it is available, I am just loading that for instance. Additionally, that won't solve my problem. All I want is to stop the iteration at some fix accuracy.

Comment: Probably better to use `While` or `NestWhile` than `Do` with an `If`-`Break`.

Comment: While playing with this: when I choose an initial value for `chsq`, it *does not change* with each iteration. You probably want to check that part of the code.

Comment: you should reexamine the logic of this expression: `chsq = Max[Abs[1 - values/approxsoln], chsq]; `  If your solution improves you keep the last solution error measure (why?).

Comment: the curly brackets here `acc=10^{-3}` are a problem too. This makes `acc` a list and so your logical test `chsq < acc` is never true as you compare a scalar to a list.

Comment: Sorry about acc=10^{-3}. I just mistakenly wrote here in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank all for your time and for you valuable suggestions. I find the answer by myself by changing the code a bit. I am posting it here.

```
dim = 11;
<< NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`;
dat = GaussianQuadratureWeights[dim, 0, 1];
dat2 = Table[dat[[i, 2]], {i, 1, dim}];
approxsoln = Table[1, {i, 1, dim}];
f = Table[1, {i, 1, dim}];
Kn = Table[(1 - 3 dat[[i, 1]] dat[[j, 1]]), {i, 1, dim}, {j, 1, dim}];
exactsoln = Table[(8/3 - 2 dat[[i, 1]]), {i, 1, dim}];

Do[
values = f + Total[Kn approxsoln dat2, 1];
chsq = Max[Abs[1 - values/approxsoln]];
If[chsq < .000001, Break[]];
Print[iter, ",  " , approxsoln[[1]] , ",  ", exactsoln[[1]]];
approxsoln = values,{iter,1,60}]
```