# How do I improve the style, efficiency, and versatility of this code?

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, coding-style

I have a math problem that I have solved analytically. I now want to generate a number of graphs based on different parameter values. **My problem is threefold:**

1. It takes a couple of minutes to produce a single graph.
2. I am wasting time waiting until one graph is finished so that I can start the next one for different parameter values, or one for e.g. different domain and range of the plot.
3. My code seems generally badly designed.

**What I'd like is:**

1. Make the computation much more efficient, and maybe less messy in terms of code.
2. More importantly: Make it so that I can generate an arbitrary amount of graphs for different settings very easily, and wait until the computer finishes them all. An make it so that after the computation is done, I can easily change the range and domain of the graph, and its design, without the computer having to redo the underlying computations.
3. Generally improve the design of the code.

---

Here is the mathematical problem (the code is given below):

> [image]

The heaviest part of the computation seems to be in finding $t$.

I have taken as a first example, $$A(i)= \begin{cases} 0 &\text { if } i<a\\ tech\cdot(i-a) &\text { if } i\geq a\end{cases}$$
For some real number $tech$.

I use the following code to compute this problem:

```
ClearAll[x, A, i, L, K, phi, t, intA]

A[i_, tech_] := If[i > a, tech*(i - a), 0];
intA[t_?NumericQ, tech_] := 
  NIntegrate[A[i, tech]^(phi/(1 - phi)), {i, Max[a, t], 1}];

t[LK_, tech_] := 
 t[LK, tech] = 
  x /. FindRoot[A[x, tech] - ((LK/x)*intA[x, tech])^(1 - phi),
    {x, (a + 1)/2}]


L = 5;
K = 5;
phi = -0.5;
a = 0.5;
tech = 20;
cL[L_, K_, tech_] := L/t[L/K, tech];
cK[L_, K_, tech_] := K/intA[t[L/K, tech], tech];
Lab[i_, L_, K_, tech_] := If[i > t[L/K, tech], 0, cL[L, K, tech]];
Kap[i_, L_, K_, tech_] := 
  If[i > t[L/K, tech], (cK[L, K, tech])*(A[i, tech])^(phi/(1 - phi)), 
   0];

Plot[{Lab[i, L, K, tech], Kap[i, L, K, tech]*A[i, tech], 
  A[i, tech]}, {i, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]

tildeF[L_, K_, tech_] := 
  tildeF[L, K, tech] = 
   NIntegrate[(Lab[i, L, K, tech] + A[i, tech]*Kap[i, L, K, tech])^
     phi, {i, 0, 1}];
F[L_, K_, tech_] := tildeF[L, K, tech]^(1/phi);

F[5, 5, 30]
Plot3D[{F[L, K, tech]}, {L, 0, 10}, {K, 0, 10}]
```

It is especially the Plot3D that is taking most of the computation time.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough time, but here are some suggestions for Step 1:

**Speeding up $\tilde A$**

Many of the integrals are computed with overlapping domains, so there is a lot of redundant integration going on.

A first strategy to speed this up is to replace $\tilde A$ by a piecewise linear approximation that is generated by computing the integral on small intervals once; I use a three-point Gauss quadrature for that, which is faster than letting `NIntegrate` figure out again and again how to do it.

Fixing some constants

```
phi = -0.5;
a = 0.5;
tech = 20.;
A[i_] := Evaluate[If[i > a, Evaluate[tech (i - a)], 0.]];
intA[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[A[i]^(phi/(1 - phi)), {i, Max[a, t],1}];
```

This is where integration takes place:

```
n = 1000000;
Δi = (1 - a)/n;
ilist = Table[i, {i, a, 1., Δi}];
Block[{x, ω},
   {x, ω} = Most[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[3,$MachinePrecision]];
   sample = Transpose@D[α x + (1 - x) β, {{α, β}, 1}];
   cA = With[{code = A[i]},
     Compile[{{i, _Real}},
      code,
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True
      ]
     ];
   integrant = With[{code = A[i]^(phi/(1. - phi))},
     Compile[{{i, _Real}},
      code,
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True
      ]
     ];
   intervals = Transpose[{Most[ilist], Rest[ilist]}];
   intervalintegrals = 
    integrant[intervals.sample].(Δi ω);
   ];
f0 = NIntegrate[A[i]^(phi/(1 - phi)), {i, a, 1.}];
flist = Join[{f0}, Reverse@Accumulate[Reverse[intervalintegrals]]];
tildeA = Interpolation[Transpose[{ilist, flist}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

An error plot:

[image: Plot[{intA[x] - tildeA[x]}, {x, a, 1}, PlotRange -> All]]

**Speeding up the root finding**

Finding the roots of a piecewise linear function is straightforward. Here is some handwritten code that does it for solving $A(t) = \left(\frac{L}{K} \frac{1}{t} \tilde A(t) \right)^{1-\varphi}$. I use a suitable reformulation of this problem along with nearest to detect a point whose neighboring intervals contain the intersection point. Note that we do not use `tildeA` here.

```
cfindroot = 
  Compile[{{t, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}, {y0, _Real}, {index, _Integer}},
   Block[{rootinleft, α, β, yα, yβ, root = 0.1},
    rootinleft = index > 1;
    If[rootinleft,
     yα = y[[index - 1]] - y0;
     yβ = y[[index]] - y0;
     α = t[[index - 1]];
     β = t[[index]];
     If [Abs[yα - yβ] < 1. 10^-8,
      root = 0.5 (α + β),
      root = α (1. - yα/(yα - yβ)) + β yα/(yα - yβ);
      rootinleft = t[[1]] - 1. 10^-8 <= root <= t[[-1]] + 1. 10^-8;
      ]
     ];
    If[! rootinleft,
     yα = y[[index]] - y0;
     yβ = y[[index + 1]] - y0;
     α = t[[index]];
     β = t[[index + 1]];
     If [Abs[yα - yβ] < 1. 10^-8,
      root = 0.5 (α + β),
      root = α (1. - yα/(yα - yβ)) + β yα/(yα - yβ);
      If[! (t[[1]] - 1. 10^-8 <= root <= t[[-1]] + 1. 10^-8), root = -1.];
      ]
     ];
    root
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
  ];
buffer = ilist/flist cA[ilist]^(1/(1 - phi));
nearestfun = Nearest[buffer -> Automatic];
findroot = {k, l} \[Function] With[{
  root = Flatten[cfindroot[ilist, buffer, l/k, nearestfun[l/k]]]
 },
   If[Length[root] == 1, root[[1]], root]
];
```

In order to get fair and reliable timing results with `RepeatedTiming`, I have to remove memoization of `t` (it wasn't too helpfull anyways). Moreover, I make the root finding more robust by enforcing the secant-based Brent method:

```
ClearAll[t]
t[LK_] := x /. FindRoot[A[x] - ((LK/x) intA[x])^(1 - phi), {x, a, 1.},  Method -> "Brent"]
```

So, here is the test:

```
SeedRandom[666];
k = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
l = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
G[x_, k_, l_] := cA[x] - ((l/k/x) tildeA[x])^(1 - phi);
Gtrue[x_, k_, l_] := A[x] - ((l/k/x) intA[x])^(1 - phi);
Plot[{G[x, k, l], Gtrue[x, k, l]}, {x, a, 1}]
root = findroot[k, l]; // RepeatedTiming // First
trueroot = t[l/k]; // RepeatedTiming // First
G[root, k, l]
Gtrue[root, k, l]
trueroot - root
```

> 0.000026
>
> 0.055
>
> 1.66567*10^-12
>
> 1.2359*10^-6
>
> -5.25296*10^-8

This is roughly a 2000-fold speedup with an accuracy that should suffice for most applications. In order to increase the accuracy, you may consider cranking up $n$ even further.

In the way the code is written, it also threads over lists with automatic parallelization:

```
m = 100000;
l = RandomReal[{0.1, 10.}, m];
k = ConstantArray[1., m];
(root = findroot[k, l]; // RepeatedTiming // First)/m
```

> 1.1*10^-7

This is roughly 200 times faster per root than applying `findroot` to pairs of single real numbers `k` and `l`, leading of a total speedup for Step 1 of something over 400000.

Comment: With respect to generating the Gauss-Legendre quadrature rule, have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6966)?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, I did, thanks. The point is: Whenever I use a Gauss quadrature, I copy some code snippet from some random package of mine. I juast haven't updated all of them, yet...

Answer (score 4):

I will just address one part of your computation. For your particular choice of `A` and $\phi$, you can solve for `t` in terms of `L/K` (I use `lk = L/K`). First, here is your equation for `t`:

```
eqn = A[t] == (lk/t Integrate[A[i]^(\[Phi]/(1-\[Phi])),{i,t,1}])^(1-\[Phi]);
eqn //TeXForm
```

> $A(t)=\left(\frac{\operatorname{lk} \int_t^1 A(i)^{\frac{\phi }{1-\phi }} \, di}{t}\right)^{1-\phi }$

Now, let's assume that `t > 1/2` and simplify the equation:

```
eqn2 = Assuming[t>1/2, Refine[eqn/.A->(Ramp[tech (#-a)]&)/.{tech->30,a->1/2,\[Phi]->-1/2}]];
eqn2 //TeXForm
```

> $30 \left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\left(\operatorname{lk} \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ & 
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -\frac{3^{2/3} \left((2 t-1)^{2/3}-1\right)}{4 \sqrt[3]{5}} & t>1 \\
>  \left((2 t-1)^{2/3}-1\right) \operatorname{Root}\left[320 \#^3+9\&,1\right] & t<1 \\
> \end{array}
>  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right)^{3/2}}{t^{3/2}}$

Finally, let's choose the `1/2 < t < 1` branch, and solve for t:

```
Refine[
    Solve[
        (eqn2 /. pw_Piecewise :> Simplify[pw, 1/2<t<1]) && lk>0,
        t,
        Reals
    ],
    lk>0
]
```

> {{t -> Root[
>       6075 lk^6 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^6 + 
>         64 lk^9 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 
>           1]^9 + (-48600 lk^6 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^6 - 
>            192 lk^9 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^9) #1 + (156600 lk^6 Root[
>              9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^6 + 
>            192 lk^9 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^9) #1^2 + (-259200 lk^6 Root[
>              9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^6 - 
>            64 lk^9 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^9) #1^3 + (607500 lk^3 Root[
>              9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^3 + 
>            237600 lk^6 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^6) #1^4 + (-5467500 lk^3 Root[
>              9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^3 - 
>            129600 lk^6 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^6) #1^5 + (11390625 + 
>            19440000 lk^3 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^3 + 
>            43200 lk^6 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^6) #1^6 + (-136687500 - 
>            34020000 lk^3 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^3) #1^7 + (683437500 + 
>            29160000 lk^3 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^3) #1^8 + (-1822500000 - 
>            9720000 lk^3 Root[9 + 320 #1^3 &, 1]^3) #1^9 + 2733750000 #1^10 - 
>         2187000000 #1^11 + 729000000 #1^12 &, 2]}}

So, for any values of `L` and `K`, one can use the above solution to compute `t`.