# Solving 2D Integro-Differential equation numerically

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

The following problem was given to me by a friend, so I can't really guaranty that a solution exists, but if, I certainly can't find it myself...

Let us consider the following Integro-differential equation

```
eq = D[\[CapitalGamma][t, T], t] == 
   1/2 DiracDelta[T] Integrate[
      A Exp[-\[Beta] (u - C)^2] \[CapitalGamma][t, u], {u, 0, 
       Infinity}] - 
    1/(Exp[\[Sigma] - \[Alpha] T ] + 1) \[CapitalGamma][t, T] - 
    D[\[CapitalGamma][t, T], T] // TeXForm
```

> $$\Gamma ^{(1,0)}(t,T)=\frac{1}{2} \delta (T) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty }
>  A e^{\beta     \left(-(u-C)^2\right)} \Gamma (t,u) \, du-\frac{\Gamma
>  (t,T)}{e^{\sigma -\alpha     T}+1}-\Gamma ^{(0,1)}(t,T),$$

where
$$A\in [0,1]\quad \beta,C,\sigma,\alpha=\text{const.}>0.$$
My friend was a bit vague about the initial conditions, but I think the following two must certainly apply
$$\Gamma(0,T)=e^{-(T-5)^2}\quad T\in [0,10], \quad \Gamma(t,T<0)=0.$$
I'm quite sure that this isn't enough (at least something in regards to $\partial \Gamma/\partial t$ should probably be known as well), so just assume the simplest case possible.

---

Now I tried finding methods to solve this here on Stack Exchange, but all of them seemed rather specific (applying the Laplace-Transformation to the equation, [taking the derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148541/numerically-solve-an-integro-differential-equation), [etc.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192123/solving-an-integro-differential-equation-with-mathematica)) and I'm not really sure if these methods work for my problem. Also the delta-function is something that I don't really know how to deal with in Mathematica... and of course the fact that I have function of two variables instead of the standard case with one...

Can someone suggest a method of solving this, or how one could approach a problem like this?

Comment: Even without the integration this PDE is troublesome enough for numeric method. Do you know if the solution involves discontinuity or non-smoothness? Some related posts: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145479/1871 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28744/5331

Comment: @xzczd Just looking at what $\Gamma$ represents, I would assume the solution to be at least continuos. Not sure if it is smooth or not..

Comment: Since there's a `A Exp[-\[Beta] (u - C)^2]` inside the integral, the method mentioned in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73974/1871 might worth trying. (The `DiracDelta` needs to be replaced by a carefully chosen continuous approximation of course, the grid size must be dense enough, and `{u, -Infinity, 
       Infinity}` will be approximated by `{u, 0, 10}`. )

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for the link and the advice. I will give it a try, but my experience with Mathematica is rather limited to easier problems, so we'll see how this goes..

Comment: @xzczd I'm currently looking into the example you have given in your second comment. I don't really get how you generate the `grid` there... Could you maybe help me with that for this case here..

Comment: That's the node for Gauss quadrature. If you find it hard to understand, you may turn to trapezoid rule as shown here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175784/1871

Comment: @xzczd thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into it tonight and see how far I can come with it.